# how to test a component that having a form with form controls as @Input()

Tags: angular4-forms

I have 2 components. I declared a form with form controls in parent component. I am passing this form to child component.

Parent component:

```
this.partyDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
  partySymbol: new FormControl('', []),
  partyFullName: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
  CustomValidator.nameValidator])),
  partyAbbreviation: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
  CustomValidator.nameValidator]))
});
```

Html:

now I am trying to test the form in the child component.. but it is not coming...

how can I test it

this error is coming

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) PartyDetailsComponent should create FAILED
[INFO]  TypeError: undefined is not an object

Comment: how you are passing control from parent to child

Comment: using component like <child [form]="partyDetailsForm "></child>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I got this answer...

 I am declaring the form in the parent so the form is not available in the 
 child component so that exception is coming...


The solution is we have to declare a form and pass it to the child component 
in spec file @Component...  like this  

 describe('CustomComponent', () => {
 // let component: CustomComponent;
// let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomComponent>;
let component: TestHostComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [CustomComponent, TestHostComponent],
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule, 
 HttpModule],
  })
  .compileComponents();
 }));

  beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });
 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });

  @Component({
   selector: `host-component`,
   template: `    <app-custom [fieldOneName]="'test'" [color]="'red'" 
   [formName]="custom_Form" [fieldOneDefaultMessage]="'enterUserName'" 
   [firstFieldType]="'text'"
   [fieldOneInvalidMessage]=" 'Person name Start with Alphabeat' " 
   [fieldOneMandatoryMessage]="'Person Name is Mandatory'"
   [label]="'test'" [required]="true">
   </app-custom> `
  })
 class TestHostComponent {
  custom_Form: FormGroup
   ngOnInit(){
    this.custom_Form = new FormGroup({
     test: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
    CustomValidator.emailValidator]))
   });
 }
```

}
});